# Breaking promise chain after the first error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, promise, ecmascript-6

I have two consecutive asynchronous operations, the problem is that when the first is an error, the second operation is still being executed:

```
File.convertToBase64(file.files[0])
    .then(function (code) {
        let params = {
            csv: code
        };
        return new Api().createFromCSV(params);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        dispatch(showError(error));
        return false; // doesn't work
    })
    .then(function (response) {
        dispatch(showSuccess('File was imported!'));
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        dispatch(showError(error));
    });
```

So, if the first catch gets called, I don't want to execute the `.then` after it, I want the chain execution stopped. How can I deal with this?

Comment: Remove the first `catch()`. In case of an error none of the `then()` handlers will be executed and it will just fall through to the other `catch()`.

Comment: @Sirko, what if you want to treat the errors differently, i.e., the catch responsible for the first `.then()` has a different logic than the one for the second `.then()`. If I only have aone catch at the end, how do I distinguish what failed?

Comment: @EluciusFTW You can distinguish by error type or some error code. If you want to use the form as above, you could also throw a dummy error inside the first `catch()` callback, so that the other `then()` functions are skipped.